# How can (-) seemingly have two different types?

Tags: haskell

In ghci, when I type

```
:t (-)
```

to figure out the type of `(-)`, it returns

```
(-) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

However, when I write `-1` haskell returns a number, which seems to imply that `(-)` is of type `Num a => a -> a`. How can `(-)` seemingly have two different types?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This was a design decision in the language. `-1` is a number, but its usage in this context is *not related to the function `(-)`*. (As Ackdari mentions in their answer, this usage is related to the function `negate`.) There are a couple compromises that allow this to work:

1. You cannot take a right slice of the `(-)` operator. As a workaround, Haskell provides the `subtract` function.
2. You cannot write a negative integer without parentheses unless it is at the beginning of an assignment (e.g. directly after `=` or `->`). This produces a parse error:

   ```
   let x = 8 * -1
   ```

   Instead, it should be written as

   ```
   let x = 8 * (-1)
   ```

   However, this is fine:

   ```
   let x = -1 * 8
   ```

These were considered to be reasonable tradeoffs to the designers of the language.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is already descirbed in the [haskell-wiki](http://wiki.haskell.org/Unary_operator), it states

> The unary minus is syntactic sugar for the Prelude function `negate`

so the function `(-)` is always the `a - b` function and if you write code like
`let x = -y` the compiler will translate it to `let x = negate y`.

Answer (score 6):

Unary minus is special in Haskell. [As stated in section 3.4 of the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-280003.4):

> The special form `-e` denotes prefix negation, the only prefix operator in Haskell, and is syntax for `negate (e)`. The binary `-` operator does not necessarily refer to the definition of `-` in the Prelude; it may be rebound by the module system. However, unary `-` will always refer to the `negate` function defined in the Prelude. There is no link between the local meaning of the `-` operator and unary negation.

Comment: One-sentence answers are discouraged on SO, as are links without a summary of their contents, since they can become broken.

Comment: As can I assume that links to reports/standards are also greatly pessimized as compared to wikis/tutorials/youtube videos?

Comment: @bipll Yes. The issue with link-only answers isn't the quality of the link target, but rather the risk of link rot. If you copied in the relevant section of the report, then your answer would be fine.